# How can i set default value in a dropdown with docusign api

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I try to setup the default value in an item list.

From DocuSign portal i can do this

[image]

with API i try the following but i cant find the default value property.

```
                        dropdownItems.Add(new ListItem()
                        {
                            Text = listItem.Text,
                            Value = listItem.value,
                            Selected = listItem.Selected.ToLower()
                            //Default= true???
                        });
                    

                    var dropdownListTabId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    signerDropDownListTab = new List<List>()
                {
                    new List() {
                        Font =  "TimesNewRoman",
                        TabLabel = s.DropdownList.ListLabel,
                        ListItems = dropdownItems,
                        DocumentId = uniqueDocumentId.ToString(),
                        PageNumber = currentSignersPage.ToString(),
                        RecipientId = uniqueRecipientId,
                        XPosition = (LocX-120).ToString(),
                        YPosition = (LocY+15).ToString(),
                        TabId = dropdownListTabId,
                        Width = "110",
                        Required = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.DropdownList.Required)? s.DropdownList.Required.ToLower() :null
                    }
                };
```

Answer (score 1):

The "Selected" field should be set to "true" and that item will be the default.

```
dropdownItems.Add(new ListItem()
{
    Text = listItem.Text,
    Value = listItem.value,
    Selected = "true"
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but with selected property I can't change my selection on signing session.

Comment: Do you mean the drop-down is now read-only?

Comment: Not sure what you did, I tied it and it works ok

Answer (score 0):

In your API request, you need to include `listItems` for *all* of your possible list values.

Add selected: "true" to the default list item